# .net 4 MVC 2 Elmah is logging background-image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, elmah

I am using Elmah in my MVC 2 project and everything works fine - except that Elmah is logging my background-image as an not implemented controller (see http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/834/unbenannt1ak.png/).

This image is set in my css via

```
body
{
background: #d9dbea url('scanlines.png');
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Perhaps you could post your routing configuration.

Comment: you mean in the global asax? It is pretty much default: 'public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("elmah.axd");
            
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Routenname
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        }'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I finally got this one...

It seems to be a "common" bug, that Elmah logs the `favicon.ico` if it is not located in your root directory. In order to overcome this problem you might create a filter as follows. I only had to add another filter rule so that Elmah does not log the `scanlines.png` (or just *another image*) as I said before. The filter rule is

```
<errorFilter>
<test>
  <and>
    <equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="404" type="Int32" />
    <or>
      <regex binding="Context.Request.ServerVariables['URL']"
             pattern="/favicon\.ico(\z|\?)" />
      <regex binding="Context.Request.ServerVariables['URL']"
             pattern="/scanlines\.png(\z|\?)" />
      <regex binding="Context.Request.ServerVariables['URL']"
             pattern="/yourimage\.jpg(\z|\?)" />
    </or>
  </and>
</test>
</errorFilter>
```

**With this you are able to block unwanted images logged by Elmah.** Hope this might help someone ;-)